# Carto.js Infowindow Listeners open/close Events

Tags: leaflet, carto, carto-js

I have a website with the carto.js library and some layers loaded. If I click on a feature, an Infowindow is opening up.

I know that there is an event for the feature click:

```
sublayer.on('featureClick', function(e, latlng, pos, data) {
          alert("Hey! You clicked " + data.cartodb_id);
    });
  }).on('error', function() {
        //log the error
});
```

But I have not found any information on how to listen for the close event. Is it possible to create a listener on the close event of the infowindow?

Usecase: Change map content while the popup is open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this example, it's using a custom infowindow but has the important bits you need. It's all about accessing the backbone model and then subscribing to the visibility change.

http://bl.ocks.org/jsanz/d74d38a3410ab9b9816defea31e7d401

Comment: Thanks, that looks good. Something I just saw is that if I switch between infowindows, without explicitly closing it, no event is fired. Do you know if there is a good solution to that or do I have to combine `featureClick` and visibility change?

Comment: I'd say so, yes

Comment: I combined featureClick and visibility change and have nice results with that, thanks a lot!